# How can I split a 5mb+ Azure ARM template into smaller templates?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

My ADF ARM template size has exceeded 5MB , and now we are facing issues dueing deployment. How can I split this single ARM template into multiple templates and use as part of nested template deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [ARM template best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/best-practices).

> You can exceed some template limits by using a nested template. For more information, see [Using linked and nested templates when deploying Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates).

Taken from the "linked and nested templates" article linked above:

> To deploy complex solutions, you can break your Azure Resource Manager template (ARM template) into many related templates, and then deploy them together through a main template. The related templates can be separate files or template syntax that is embedded within the main template. This article uses the term **linked template** to refer to a separate template file that is referenced via a link from the main template. It uses the term **nested template** to refer to embedded template syntax within the main template.
>
> [...]
>
> To nest a template, add a deployments resource to your main template. In the template property, specify the template syntax.
>
> ```json
> {
>  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
>  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
>  "parameters": {},
>  "variables": {},
>  "resources": [
>    {
>      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
>      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
>      "name": "nestedTemplate1",
>      "properties": {
>        "mode": "Incremental",
>        "template": {
>          <nested-template-syntax>
>        }
>      }
>    }
>  ],
>  "outputs": {
>  }
> }
> ```

Comment: Note that nesting the template in another deployment won't help with the size limit... it will actually make the json file larger.  Nesting can help with limits like the resource count.  If you want everything in one deployment, then you can use linked templates or templateSpecs - or just put different resources into different JSON files.